# How do I extract text at even positions?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am extracting a page with Nokogiri which returns a Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet. From this, I would like to extract only the text from even nodes.

```
doc.search("h2 a").class #=> Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
doc.search("h2 a").count #=> returns 148
```

I am interested in 0,2,4,8, etc.:

```
doc.search("h2 a")[0].text #=> the one I wanted.
doc.search("h2 a")[2].text #=> the one I wanted.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the below :

```
doc.search("h2 a").map.with_index(0) do |i,nd|
    i.text if nd.even?
end.compact
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want every even-positioned `a` node:

```
doc.search("h2 a:nth-child(even)")
```

or perhaps you are looking for every other node over all:

```
doc.search("h2 a").select.with_index{|a, i| i.even?}
```